# jquery array into selector string/format

Tags: jquery

I have an array called selected as follows :

```
var selected = [];
```

example value of selected from console would return :

```
["97", "98", "99", "101", "103", "105", "106"]
```

I need to turn these into a multiple selector of ids... for example :

```
$('#97', '#98', '#99', '#101', '#103', '#105', '#106').click( function () {
    alert('hi');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution: use `join`.

Example:

http://jsbin.com/qihep/1/edit?js,output

```
var selected = 
    ["97", "98", "99", "101", "103", "105", "106"];

var selector = "#" + selected.join(", #");
```

Browser compatibility is perfect, as per:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join#Browser_compatibility

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LQb6a/)</kbd>

```
$('#' + ["97", "98", "99", "101", "103", "105", "106"].join(',#')).click(function(){
  //code here
});
```

---

[arr.join(separator)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

---

```
'#' + ["97", "98", "99", "101", "103", "105", "106"].join(',#')
```

`#` for the first element than all other elements are joined by `.join(',#')` i.e `,#`

---

In case of variable use it like this

```
'#' + selected.join(',#')
```